# Is there a way to ignore questions with a specified number of down votes?

Tags: support

When I say specified number of down votes, I mean a total vote count of less than -2, or ,-3, etc. My favourite SE site attracts a lot of new users that ask off topic questions. Instead of sifting through all the garbage, I'd like to simply hide all questions that don't have at least a score of 0 or more. I'd be happy if there was a way to hide questions from users with a rep count of 5 or less too, so their questions wouldn't appear in my feed until they at least go one up vote. Is there anyway to do this? Or would this be a feature request?

Comment: -1 I want this implemented so that I don't see this question. _/sarcasm_

Comment: @yo Right? Useful.

Comment: +1, to reflect 162 upvotes at similar question at MSO: [Allow users to optionally filter out low-quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) (which was additionally followed by 4-phase series of [New “recommended” homepage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276840/839601) posts, all heavily upvoted)

Comment: @ShemSeger For the record, I really didn't downvote this one.

Comment: @yo - It wouldn't have bothered me if you did. In fact, it didn't, even when I thought you had.

Comment: The homepage already filters out questions below a certain score, (-3 on most non-meta sites) you just can't configure what that value is, and it doesn't apply to question views other than the homepage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a couple of the advanced search options, you can obtain a list of all questions with a score of at least 0.  Type the following into the search box:

`is:question score:0..`

The `is:question` option specifies only questions, and the `score:0..` option filters out questions with a negative score.

When I type that into the Meta.SE search box, I get [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A0..).  The search results are sorted by relevance.  You probably want the questions sorted by "newest" or "active" instead, so you can click one of those sort options.

Here are the search results sorted by [newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A0..) questions.  Here are the search results sorted by [active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A0..) questions.

Notice that the URL for the search results sorted by newest questions looks like the following:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a0..`

To show all the questions with a score of at least 0 (sorted by newest) on your favorite SE site, just replace `meta.stackexchange.com` in the URL with the domain name of that site.  Then bookmark that URL in your browser.

Comment: New favourite! Just made this my new bookmark for the site. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This would be incredibly bad for a community. No new users would get upvotes because people would block them. This would mean no one could join the community.

On top of that, you wouldn't be voting for those bad questions - community moderation is one of the main principles of SE. People stop voting up / down, questions aren't sorted. You wouldn't get the chance to edit it into a good question and turn it around, and later, as you get close vote privileges, you wouldn't be able to tidy up the site.

On top of that, what if there is a good answer that you would have seen and upvoted otherwise?

New users / bad questions still need attention from experienced community members.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250629/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-questions-with-a-specified-number-of-down-votes#comment818125_250629

Comment: A bad question doesn't deserve good answers. A bad question doesn't deserve any answers.

Comment: You're making the assumption that all new users will post bad questions that get downvotes.  That's just not true at all.  As for moderation, people who want to spend their time contributing by reviewing content and performing moderation actions certainly are welcome to, but it is not an *expectation* whatsoever.  People who are only here to ask/answer questions are more than welcome to do just that.

Comment: This answer is a tad melodramatic

Comment: @Servy "I'd be happy if there was a way to hide questions from users with a rep count of 5 or less too, so their questions wouldn't appear in my feed until they at least go one up vote."